# From Wigner classification to field equations

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, representation-theory, invariants

Wigner classification of elementary particles tells us how many different particle types we should expect if we want their dynamic to be invariant under the Poincare group. The classification is done by using the eigenvalues $P^{2}=m^{2}$ and $W^{2}=S$ of the two Casimir  $P^{\mu}P_{\mu}$ and $W^{\mu}W_{\mu}$. ($P^{\mu}$ is the four-momentum associated with the field and $W^{\mu}$ is the Pauli-Lubanski vector).
So we can classify all particles\fields into 4 categories:

- vector fields: $m^{2} \neq 0$, $S=1,2...$;
- spinor fields: $m^{2} \neq 0$, $S=\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}...$;
- wigner fields: $m^{2} = 0$, $S\neq 0$;
- scalar fields: $m^{2} \neq 0$, $S=0$;

We know that to each one of these fields it corresponds a field equation (Klein-Gordon for scalar particles, Dirac/Proca for vector and spinor fields), so it should be possible to derive them by using this classification. I found an exemple on how to do it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_classification in the section "massive scalar fields",  where the Klein-Gordon equation is derived.
If we have $m^2 \neq 0$ and $S=0$ the general unitary representation of the Poincare group reduces to:

\begin{equation} 
\rho(a,\Lambda)=e^{i\alpha_{\mu}P^{\mu}+ \frac{i}{2}\omega_{\mu\nu}\not{J^{\mu\nu}}}=e^{i\alpha_{\mu}P^{\mu}}=e^{i(\alpha_{0}E +\alpha_{k}P^{k})}
\end{equation}
so the action on a scalar field $\phi(p_{\mu}) \in L^2[M]$ (I think the $L^2[M]$ space comes up because we want all physical fields to vanish at infinity) is the product:
\begin{equation}
\phi'(p_{\mu}')=e^{i(\alpha_{0}E +\alpha_{k}P^{k})}\phi(p_{\mu})
\end{equation}

How may a proceed to find the Klein Gordon equation? I tried by making the summation in the exponential explicit and than inserting the measure $E^{2}-P_{1}^{2}-P_{2}^{2}-P_{3}^{2}=m^{2}$, but I can't find the right result.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly meant $W^2 = 0$ for the cases $P^2 = 0$, since the question of what the sub-class $W^2 > 0$ and $P^2 = 0$ (the "cylindrical" luxons) correspond to has never, as far as I'm aware, been satisfactorily resolved. The photons belong in the class $W^2 = 0$, $P^2 = 0$.

For tardyons, using your notation, $P^2 > 0$, and one may then define $m$ by setting $P^2 = m^2$; and, as a consequence of $P^2 > 0$, one also has $W^2 ≥ 0$. So, one can set $W^2 = m^2 S^2$ (writing $S$ this way, instead of with your notation), with $S$ being the magnitude-squared of the spin 3-vector.

The scalar case corresponds to $S^2 = 0$, which you started developing, while the cases where $S^2 > 0$ are handled by treating the spin vector $$ as a quantized representation of $SO(3)$ - which already includes the scalar representation $S^2 = 0$ as one of its cases. So, it's a product of the state space for $S^2 = 0$ and the discrete state space for the $SO(3)$ representation.

For luxons, $P^2 = 0$ and, as a consequence also: $W^2 ≥ 0$. The cases $W^2 > 0$ (the "cylindrical" luxons) have never, to my knowledge, been treated. For them, the 3-vector part of $W$ has a cylinder as a locus. The cases $W^2 = 0$ are probably what you meant.

If $W = 0$, these are the scalar luxons, handled analogously to the tardyons, but with $m = 0$. If $W ≠ 0$, these are the "helical" luxons, which includes the photons.

For this class, the vector part of $W$ is collinear with the vector part of $P$, and the 4-vector $W$ has 0 inner product with the 4-vector $P$. The ratio of the vector part of $W$ to the vector part of $P$ is an invariant and is - up to multiples of $c$ - the helicity, itself; where helicity is defined as the component of the angular momentum 3-vector parallel to the momentum 3-vector.

In Weinberg's treatment (in section 2.5 of Volume 1 of "The Quantum Theory Of Fields") he does, indeed, slip in that extra assumption. The free components of $W$ that trace out a cylinder are, in his notation, $A$ and $B$, up to proportionality.

He starts developing the case, but at some point in the process he basically says "Oh, hell. Just forget about it. We've never seen any of these cases before in nature." (to paraphrase) and drops them, setting $(A,B) = (0,0)$, i.e. narrowing focus only to eigenstates of $(A,B) = (0,0)$. Up to proportionality, $W^2 = A^2 + B^2$.

That drops you down to the helical subclass of luxons and, in it, the helicity (which he terms $J_3 = σ$) is an invariant property of the representation. You can look at his progress past this point to get a view of how that's laid out. I'm not as familiar with it, so I can't say anything more about it here.